# ng-class apply outside of ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

```
<ul class="listing listing-sm small" ng-class="{'divider': (model.selections | filter:filter).length > 0}">
  <li ng-repeat="selection in model.selections | filter:filter" ng-class="{highlight: selection.on}">
```

Is there a better way to add the class on the ul without running the data through the filter 2x (on the ul and the ng-repeat)?

Comment: Could you not use a class at all and instead use `:not(:empty)` as a CSS rule? (looks like you're just checking for not-empty lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the filter in a callback function and check the length their and change a flag accordingly to the result.

```
<ul class="listing listing-sm small" ng-class="{'divider':hasResults}">
    <li ng-repeat="selection in manualFilter(model.selections)" ng-class="{highlight: selection.on}">
```

And in the js:

```
$scope.manualFilter = function(selections) {
     var result = $filter('filter')(selections);
     if (result.length > 0 ) {
              $scope.hasResults = true;
     } else {
              $scope.hasResults = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: I get this message: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: manualFilterFilterProvider <- manualFilterFilter`

Comment: Solved it by doing changing the ng-repeat to:
`selection in manualFilter(model.selections)`

and added `return result` to the end of the $scope.manualFilter function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `$index` and a variable called `$scope.selected` and use
`ng-class = "'highlight': $index === selected"`